# print missing number from array of numbers between 1 to N

Tags: arrays

you got an array of size K filled with numbers between 1..N print all the numbers between 1 to N that are missing from this array. 
the solution should work in the best complexibility.

thanks.

Comment: Where's your code attempt?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i := n - k + 1 to n
    A[i] := A[1]
end for

for i := 1 to n - k
    while A[A[i]] != A[i] 
        swap(A[i], A[A[i]])
    end while
end for

for i := 1 to n
    if A[i] != i then 
        print i
    end if
end for
```

The code runs in O(n) time. The swaps only occur `if A[i] != i`.